# DocuSign Api -How to resend an account activation for a pending user

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to resend an invitation to an existing user using REST API but I receive an error.

In the [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Users/Users/update/) I have not seen anything about it.

Is it possible to resend an account activation for a pending user?

Answer (score 1):

Using the DocuSign REST api, you will NOT be able to resend an account activation for a pending user.

However you can do it through the [Docusign Admin website](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-welcome-to-administration).